# 2sxc razor template - display data from DNN user profile fields

Tags: dotnetnuke, user-profile, 2sxc

I have a content module set up to use a razor template and need it to pull data from a field in the user's profile. I can get it to show name, email, etc. with the @Dnn.User.Email format, but I can't get any of the custom profile fields.

I used the helper snippets to try to get the right format - went to the "Dnn user information" drop down, clicked on Profile > AnyValue. It inserted this: @Dnn.User.Profile.GetPropertyValue(${1:City}\)

I do have a city field but that code breaks the template. "error CS1056: Unexpected character '$' at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()" is the start of the error message on the page.

I tried to change the code in the ending () but no change I made got it to work.

Is that not the code to use to pull the user profile fields? I can't find any other documentation that goes over the profile - just module, portal, tab and user.

Comment: This isn't quite an answer to your question, you are not limited the the items provided directly by 2sxc. You can also make calls to pretty everything in the DNN API.  You can even call methods in other modules, too.

I've used 2sxc to retrieve a list of upcoming events from an event planner module and use them as I want.

Comment: Not sure I would know where to start with anything like that. Any documentation you can point me to? I just need data from a custom profile property.

Comment: The DNN Docs site (https://dnndocs.com/api/DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.html) is a good place to start.

https://dnndocs.com/api/DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.html is the section that introduces you to the Users api.

In your razor script, you just need to "use" the right namespaces, and then you are on your way.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That may be over my head, but I'll definitely save it should I need to try it in the future. I was able to get it working with the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the snippet did something wrong - the $-syntax is a placeholder for the editor to let you replace the texts with tab-tab-tab.

Basically you want something like this:

```
@Dnn.User.Profile.GetPropertyValue("City")
```

As Joe pointed out, any DNN API will work - Dnn.User is actually the normal UserInfo object of DNN.

If you want to query users etc. you can use the DnnUserProfile data source (https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.DataSources.DnnUserProfile.html) to create visual queries or using code, and of course you can always just use the normal DNN API.

Comment: Thank you! That worked great. I think I'd tried just City, but not with the quotes.